# how to remove 'Chapter' word only from headings?

Tags: header-footer, chapters

I want to suppress the word 'chapter' from my headings but to leaving the normal 'CHAPTER X: Name of the chapter' in the document.

I want that my headings says '# Name of the chapter', not 'Chapter # Name of the chapter'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without information about the `documentclass` you are using or the type of document you are writing, I wrote a quite "basic" answer.

This can be easily achieved with the `fancyhdr` package; the default style is:

```
\fancypagestyle{DefaultStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{} %Clean headers
    \fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \leftmark}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. {##1}}}{}}
}
```

In order to remove the word "Chapter" from the header, one can simply remove `\chaptername` from the `\chaptermark` definition:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

% Random text
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Page style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Defining the new page style
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{} %Clean headers
    \fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. {\slshape{##1}}}{}}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{MyStyle}
\chapter{First chapter title}
\lipsum

\chapter{Second chapter title}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Broken as of 2021.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is using package `scrlayer-scrpage`. Then you can redefine the command `\chaptermarkformat` to get the desired layout.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage[automark,markcase=noupper,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter.\enskip}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```