# Edit the leftmark command

Tags: report

I want to edit the \leftmark so it just displays the number and the title of the chapter.  I have shown a minimal example of my document below. Instead of “Chapter 1. The first chapter”, I just want the \leftmark command to show: “1. The first chapter”.  How do I solve this ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{Mainstyle}{%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[L]{Something}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{Mainstyle}
\chapter{The first chapter}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{The first section in first chapter}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{The second section in first chapter}
\lipsum[2]

\chapter{The second chapter}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{The first section in second chapter}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{The second section in second chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you switch to the memoir class, this will be very easy with the build in features.

Comment: See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262385/how-to-remove-chapter-word-only-from-headings/262387#262387